# Activate elements in the navigation bar when the user scrolls to sections of my one-page website

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, uinavigationbar

I am trying to apply [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/) to my website, but I can't get it right.

I added these lines

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="jQuery/navigation.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> <!--original script-->
```

between the header tags of my html file and adapted my navigation bar like so:

```
<nav class="floatingMenu" id="floatingMenu">
  <ul id="#top-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Top</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#one">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#two">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#three">three</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#four">four</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#five">five</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#six">six</a></li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

And here is the css class with the propriety I would like the element in the menu to take.

```
.active {font-size:30px;}
```

where am I mistaken?
Thanks!

Edit: Here is the content of my jQuery/navigation.js:

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
topMenu = $("#floatingMenu"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
// All list items
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
        return item;
    }
});

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function (e) {
var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1;
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
}, 300);
e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function () {
// Get container scroll position
var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

// Get id of current scroll item
var cur = scrollItems.map(function () {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop) return this;
});
// Get the id of the current element
cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    // Set/remove active class
    menuItems.parent().removeClass("active")
        .end().filter("[href=#" + id + "]").parent().addClass("active");
}

});
```

Comment: Please post the javascript that you are using.

Comment: Thank you @joshhunt. I edited the post and added the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In the JS on the fiddle you linked there is this:

```
topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
```

You need:

```
topMenu = $("#floatingMenu"),
```

Comment: Thank you @fran-varney. Unfortunately the script doesn't work yet, but we're getting closer with your contribution.

Comment: Can you paste your css as well? Or make a jsfiddle?